# Reconnecting JDBC failover hosts on Spring with BoneCP pooling

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, bonecp

I configured my Spring Boot application to use BoneCP with PostgreSQL's failover mechanism (`jdbc:postgresql://host1:port,host2:port,host3:port/my_db?currentschema=public`) by providing several hosts that contain the same replicated database.

When doing tests, I have observed that if the connection is dropped, the application will return a `PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend` followed by several `PersistenceException` to the web browser (E.g when requesting stored data) and won't try to switch to the next available host unless the user manually reloads the page triggering a reconnection.

I would like to catch these exceptions and force a reconnection (Or up to X reconnections, with Y ms between each, if possible) before anything is returned to the user. Naturally, if all hosts are unreachable (Or a different issue appears) an exception would be thrown as usual